# Skipping an ExpressionEngine Chanel Entry

Tags: php, expression, expressionengine

So I'm working on the EE build, and I'm having a little issue skipping channel entries that have already passed.

I put in the date parameter to only show those with an end date that is greater than or equal to the current time, still didn't work.

So I came up with an if then statement idea. If the channel entry is in the past it will just skip it and go to the next one. Continuously doing this until an entry that is suitable works.

I guess my question is if there is a way to make an offset a global variable?

SN: The build wasn't done the best, which is why the ideas that I came up with that normally would work don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag so that we can more effectively debug your issue? Just going off of what you've written, it seems like you may have used an incorrect 'date' parameter. The correct parameter to use is the [`start_on` parameter](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on). The documentation for that parameter shows example code for ignoring entries that were published in the past and should clear up any questions you have about how to implement it.

Please elaborate on your question if you still need help!

**Updated answer:**

Hey Jamal, thanks for posting your code. I would definitely set your `start_on` parameter to `start_on="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'}"` and then troubleshoot from there. If you're seeing an error or no generated code after making this change, it's most likely a sign of a problem somewhere else and should be fixed.

You could try hard coding a date for the `start_on` parameter, like so:

```
start_on="2012-06-18 03:39"
```

You could also try adding `dynamic="no"` to the tag, but I can't recall if that 's supposed to change anything in this instance.

If you're still having trouble with this parameter, please turn on template debugging and EE's output profiler (both found in *Admin > System Administration > Output and Debugging* ), refresh the page, and try to determine what the issue is based off of the debugging info that appears on the screen.

Comment: Here it is, {exp:channel:entries channel="news_articles" limit="1" orderby="end_date" sort="asc" show_future_entries="yes" start_on="{current_time}"}. The start_on parameter was in place and it wasn't responding or when I called the format the space would just go blank

Comment: That's what I put for the current_time parameter at first, that's when it went blank in the area the entries are suppose to show. I figured out the blank area indicates that the older entries are still getting pulled, but since they aren't set up with any code to be displayed they just show a blank space. I started doing the debugging earlier, but got pulled into something else. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explain what "end_date" signifies here.

Is that a custom field, with a date in it?  You are sorting on it, but you are also using the start_on parameter.  start_on parameter looks at entry_date not your custom field.

So basically your tag is saying…

"Give me one record with an entry_date in the future with the smallest value for end_date."

This could easily result in the return of records where end_date is a date in the past.

Comment: End date is a custom field with a date in it. I know that start_on looks at entry date, and the old entry has a date set to one year ago and it still shows up.

Comment: I think Bitmanic has solved it with his updated answer.  You must format the current_time before passing it to start_on.  start_on="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'}"